# Sharepoint Angular REST add item yields 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: jquery, angularjs, rest, sharepoint

I have been banging my head against the wall for a couple of days now. I'm trying to add an item to a list in Sharepoint with Angular js.

Retrieving items is smoot but adding items doesn't work for me.

Code:

```
spApp.controller('spListCtrl', function($scope, $http, $q) {
    $http.post("https://tools.site.com/_api/lists/getbytitle('PersonalFilter')/items", {
        'Title': 'TEST'
    }, {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose',
            'X-RequestDigest': $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        }
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("YES");
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {});
});
```

I have done this before with jQuery Ajax (in a similar fashion) but I can't seem to locate the problem.

The script is running on the same site as to where the call is made, so no Cross-Domain calling. Furthermore this is embedded with the script editor, so this is running directly inside a Sharepoint Masterpage.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried passing data after stringifying like following. Give it a try.
var data = JSON.stringify(
            {   data:{
                'Title' : 'Test'
            }
            });

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error might occur due to the following reasons:

**1.Invalid List Item payload**

In particular the format of `body` attribute  must have the following format for list item:

```
$http({
          data: { Title : 'John Doe', __metadata:  {type: 'SP.Data.ContactsListItem' }},  
          //remaining parameters are omitted for clarity 
      });
```

where

- `Title` is a property of List Item
- `__metadata` attribute is a **mandatory** and  specifies the entity type of List Item (in your case this atribute is missing, in my case since it is a
  `Contacts` list, the value is `SP.Data.ContactsListItem`) See *About
  List Item entity type* section below that describes how to determine entity
  type of list item.

**2. Missing header `Content-Type`**

`Content-Type` have to be specified, for example:

```
$http({
         headers: {
                    "Content-Type" : "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    //...                 
                  }          
 });
```

---

The following example demonstrates how to create List Item using SharePoint 2013/Online REST.

**Example**

```
$scope.createContact = function() {

      var endpointUrl = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Contacts')/items";
      var itemPayload = { Title : 'John Doe', __metadata:  {type: 'SP.Data.ContactsListItem' }};

      $http({
               method: "POST",
               url : endpointUrl,
               data: itemPayload,  
               headers: {
                           "Content-Type" : "application/json;odata=verbose",
                           "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                           "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val() 
                        }          
      }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {  
          //Process List Item
          var contact = data.d;
      }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {  
          //An error occured...
      });  

 }
```

### About List Item entity type

The following query allows to determine entity type of List Item:

Endpoint Uri: `https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('<list title>')?$select=ListItemEntityTypeFullName`